# Hints to find ROI

Tags: c++, opencv

I have this image, and I want to find the ROI (only the central panel without bar and without sx and dx panel). Can I have hints to retrive the ROI with the OpenCV ?

[image: Panel]

Comment: Convert to black and white and retrieve largest Contour?

Comment: I tried but it doesn't work with any image because i have images with contours colored with warm colors i.e. orange, yellow (high temperature).

Comment: Can we see what you did? And if it is in white and black what colors have to do with it?

Comment: @FirstStep for example this: http://ecmweb.com/site-files/ecmweb.com/files/gallery_images/Infrared-Thermography-12-Solar-Panel.jpg?1443646311

Comment: well, angles from camera are a nightmare. See this that finds contours in an image https://giphy.com/gifs/26BRC2hzvCVSeIX4s